# programming assembly under Linux

Tags: loops, assembly, arm7

i write a exam about arm 7 assembly and i would like to write some code on my Linux Mint computer.
Is it possible to write some basic code (Hello World, simply loops...) in the console an compile it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - simply use `gcc` to assemble files with a ".s" or ".S" extension. Alternatively, you can use `as` to directly assemble files.

Comment: Thank you, it is also possible to simulate the register of the arm?

Comment: What do you mean? You can access the registers directly.

Comment: I think you can write ARM assembly---No problem. But the assembly code you wrote for ARM won't run on your Linux Mint computer, if that is what you want. If you want to write some X86/64(supposing you're using such an architecture for your linux mint computer), you can use GAS(in gnu binutils) but you probably won't simulate the registers of arm because they are of different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers
@  xiangpisaiMM, yes that is what i want;)

i found this tutorial: http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/index.html